# Prepend value to a JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json

**Is there a possible way to prepend a value to a JSONObject in Java?**

For instance, I have a JSONObject that says:

```
{
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
    "three" : 3,
    "four" : 4,
    "five" : 5
}
```

Now I want to add another value to it, but if I say:

```
jsonObject.put("zero", 0);
```

I will be having something like this:

```
{
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
    "three" : 3,
    "four" : 4,
    "five" : 5,
    "zero" : 0
}
```

But is there a way I can prepend a new value maybe something like `jsonObject.prepend("zero", 0);` so I will be having

```
{
    "zero" : 0,
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
    "three" : 3,
    "four" : 4,
    "five" : 5
}
```

**Note:** I am having a random keys, just used this one as example. I don't even know the keys, I extract them from my database, so there is no way I should be sorting the keys

Comment: From document: A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs, so i think it's not possible .... You might use other solution like sorted Collection/Map... Or try constructing jsonObject from sortedMap.

Comment: @huy... Okay man, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I had to find a way out to this one. It look's little bit dirty, but it works perfectly well.

I had to create my own **JsonObject** class extending **JSONObject** to it, then add a prepend method

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class JsonObject extends JSONObject {

    //create method to prepend object
    public JsonObject prepend(String key, Object object) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray keysArray = this.names();  //save the object keys
        JSONArray objArray = new JSONArray();
        Iterator iterator = this.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            String k = (String) iterator.next();
            objArray.put(this.get(k));   //save the object
        }
        this.removeAll();    // empty the JsonObject
        this.put(key, object);    // now it's empty, put the new object, making it to be the 1st(prepending trick)
        assert keysArray != null;
        if(keysArray.length() > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < keysArray.length(); i++) {
                String exKey = keysArray.getString(i);
                assert objArray != null;
                Object o = objArray.get(i);
                if(!key.equals(exKey))
                    this.put(exKey, o);    // put back the saved keys and object
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    // method to empty the JsonObject
    public void removeAll() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray array = this.names();
        assert array != null;
        if(array.length() > 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                String key = array.getString(i);
                this.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then using it in my code

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.put("one", 1);
object.put("two", 2);
object.put("three", 3);
object.put("four", 4);
object.put("five", 5); 
object.prepend("zero", 0);
Log.i("object" object.toString());
```

**Result**

```
{
    "zero" : 0,
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
    "three" : 3,
    "four" : 4,
    "five" : 5
}
```